# No Refactor bulb, have to add NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS2015 with Visual Assist.
For some reason after a while, the tiny light bulb at the left side of my code which appeared when some refactoring could have been done, has disappeared completely.

I tried everything I could do: Set code assist in project properties, made sure I have IntelliSense active, etc.

The only helpful thing was to add the NuGet package "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform"
I don't want to Check-In this to our repository. Is there some other way to get the bulb back?

Answer (score 0):

Weird, but I quickly find the answer myself.
The problem started when I changed the .NET framework version from 4.5.2 to 4.6.1